# Python: How can I pass this return value from one method to another?

Tags: python, automation, scripting, return

So I have a class which helps me to get past dates and parse them in a specific format. I know datetime has some functionality around this but I am trying to get a wide different array of formats for my use-case.

Here is my setup so you can see where I am coming from.

I have an engine class which houses all my classes for the automation engine I am working on. Inside my engine class I have a data class and a date class.

The date class has the following method:

```
import datetime

def get_past_date(self, days_in_past):


    # getting current date
    start_date = datetime.date(
        datetime.datetime.now().year, 
        datetime.datetime.now().month,
        datetime.datetime.now().day
    )

    # getting the past day
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=days_in_past)
    past_date = start_date - delta


    # getting past date out of original format
    month = ''
    day = ''
    year = ''
    dash_count = 0
    for char in str(past_date):
        if char == '-':
            dash_count = dash_count + 1
            continue
        if dash_count == 0:
            year = year + char
        if dash_count == 1:
            month = month + char
        if dash_count == 2:
            day = day + char
    
    return (month, day, year)
```

Then I have in my data class this function.

```
import PyPDF2

def extract_cem_spreadsheet_data(engine):

    # we want to do a couple things here. First, we need to get the current month.
    past_date = engine.date.get_past_date(90)
    print(past_date)
```

The problem is that engine.date.get_past_date(90) has the correct result inside the "get_past_date" function, but it returns None after I pass the result to the "extract_cem_spreadsheet_data" function.

I've had this problem a few times in other places and hacked a few workarounds, but I really want to be able to pass the return value from "get_past_date" to "extract_cem_spreadsheet_data".

I have looked up multiple resources but can't seem to pinpoint this issue.

Thank you for your time!

I have tried searching on multiple other forums and even on stack overflow. I have not found a valid solution for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. So, I set my class structure up like this to clean up my file system and keep my classes clean.

```
import datetime
from ._get_past_date import get_past_date
from ._format_date import format_date


class date:

    def __init__(self):
        self.days_of_week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
        self.months_of_year = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

    def get_past_date(self, days_in_past): get_past_date(self, days_in_past)
    def format_date(self, date_tuple, date_format): format_date(self, date_tuple, date_format)
```

Well, I missed the return statement in this line:

```
def get_past_date(self, days_in_past): get_past_date(self, days_in_past)
```

It should be:

```
def get_past_date(self, days_in_past): return get_past_date(self, days_in_past)
```

So thank you to whoever might need this in the future. If you clean up your classes with this methodology, then you need to include a return statement in the actual body of your class.